# on/off button to show/hide content

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

We are using WordPress for our restaurant website and for our menu pages we would like to give the user the option to display an Allergen Guide alongside the menu dishes.
The allergen keys are displayed under each dish and are wrapped in a div named .allergens

The goal is to have an on/off button that will show/hide the .allergerns class, is this possible?
I’ve had a look at other solutions here but none seem to fit my purpose,

Many thanks

Nat

*EDIT*

To make it more clearer and to give a bit more background i'm currently learning the ropes, i have good knowledge of CSS and HTML but no experience with Javascript.

In simple terms i need to be able to hide or show a div class with either a CSS button or even radio buttons. I tried to accomplish this using CSS but i quickly realised the only solution is to use some Javascript code.

In the screenshot below i would wrap those coloured boxes (allergen keys) in a div with a class name (allergens) and then a button or radio buttons at the top of the page would show/hide that div.

[Menu screenshot with allergen keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAvSX.jpg)

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you made an attempt at implementing this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to do and what is the current background. The current topic of this question may be considered too broad or just off topic, because there is not a specific problem to solve but rather a vague one.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=strict&q=show+hide+div+using+javascript, Plenty of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var togBtn = $('.tog');
  var allergerns = $('.allergerns');

  togBtn.one('click', hideAllergerns);

  function hideAllergerns() {
    allergerns.fadeOut();
    togBtn.one('click', showAllergerns);
  }

  function showAllergerns() {
    allergerns.fadeIn();
    togBtn.one('click', hideAllergerns);
  }
});
```

```css
.allergerns {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #4aa3df
}

.tog {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allergerns"></div>

<button class="tog">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Hi El i got this working lovely however ho do i change the code so that the initial state on page load is to hide the element?

Comment: It's ok i figured that out, thanks.

Comment: you can give display:none to .allergerns and call (showAllergerns) function  instead of calling (hideAllergerns) function on click  https://jsfiddle.net/m60czngx/ ,

 or simply you can hide .allergerns on page load by fading it out in 0ms
allergerns.fadeOut(0); and call (showAllergerns) on click event  https://jsfiddle.net/m60czngx/1/

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but you have to be careful of what are the other native WP events for that button

**If you used jQuery:**

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#DIV').toggle();
});
```

**Just pure JavaScript:**

```
function visibility() {
       var e = document.getElementById("DIV");
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
   }
```

Call the function in the button click event

Comment: Nice answer, for putting two ways to do it, Pure JS or jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

Are you comfortable with jQuery? Because that is what you are going to need.

Basically you will need a button with a class .yourbutton (or any other class but just change it in the script as well) and the element you want to add or remove allergerns class should also have another class that will always be there. From my code example it should be "yourclass"

Then you can use this code and add it in the footer.php or attach it as a separate js file.

```
<script>
jQuery('.yourbutton').click(function(){

jQuery('.yourclass').toggleClass('allergerns');

});
</script>
```